# Mostrar valor seleccionado de checkbox en vista edit.blade

Tags: laravel, html5, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo un problema al visualizar las opciones marcadas en checkbox dentro de la vista edit.blade, cuando creo un usuario y selecciono el rol, luego en la vista edit, no queda seleccionado el valor del checkbox anteriormente marcado al crear el usuario.

Aquí dejo el código del checkbox en la vista users edit.blade:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12"> 
                <h3>Lista de roles</h3>
                <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        @foreach($roles as $role)
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, null) }}
                                    {{ $role->name }}
                                    <em>({{ $role->description }})</em>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Agrego las function de store, edit y update del controller de Usuario:

```
public function store (UsuarioFormRequest $request)

    {
        $usuario=new User;
        $usuario->name=$request->get('name');
        $usuario->email=$request->get('email');
        $usuario->password=bcrypt($request->get('password'));
        $usuario->save();

        $usuario->roles()->sync($request->get('roles'));

        return redirect()->route('users.edit', $usuario->id)
          ->with('info', 'Usuario ingresado correctamente');

    }

public function edit($id)

    {
        $usuario = User::findOrFail($id);
        $roles = Role::get();

        return view("usuario.edit", [
            "usuario" => $usuario,
            "roles" => $roles
        ]);
    }    


    public function update(UsuarioFormRequest $request,$id)

    {
        $usuario=User::findOrFail($id);
        $usuario->name=$request->get('name');
        $usuario->email=$request->get('email');
        $usuario->password=bcrypt($request->get('password'));
        $usuario->update();

        $usuario->roles()->sync($request->get('roles'));

        return redirect()->route('users.edit', $usuario->id)
          ->with('info', 'Usuario actualizado correctamente');
    }
```

Agradezco ayuda y si es necesario que suba algo mas del código, favor de decirme.

Comment: Cual es la estructura que tiene tu $role?

Comment: Agregue las function del controller de Roles, no se si te refieres a esas estructuras¿? Cuando creo un usuario y selecciono el rol en el checkbox, luego en la vista edit no se guarda dicha seleccion, ese es el problema.

Comment: En tu compact estas pasando "role" y en tu vista blade estas tomando como "$roles" debes tomarlo:"$role". con el mismo formato de nombre. deberia ser : foreach ($role as $r){

Comment: Me habia equivocado al subir las functions, puse las del Controller de Roles en vez de las del Controller de Usuario, ya subi las correspondientes al post